# jquery issue with new version

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [this sample](http://jsbin.com/inudo3/edit?html,js,output) but I wish to use the latest version of Jquery.
I noticed when using Jquery-ui 1.9.0 or above, the dialog does not show up anymore. It works fine with the original version (1.0.8) available in the demo.
Same thing if I use Jquery 2.2.1 (Jquery not Jquery -ui) instead of 1.4.2

The only change I have tried was replacing `$('a.delete').live('click',function(){` by `$('delete').on('click', 'a', function(){` in order to remedy to the deprecated `.live`

I can't figure out what else needs to be changed, even after looking at the Jquery and Jquery change logs. The [Jquery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/tree/1.x-stable#readme) tool doesn't give anything wrong.

The goal of the script is to remove a line when clicking on the icon. A dialog should be displayed to invite the user to confirm/cancel.

Comment: make sure its $('.delete') -- don't forget the period before delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('delete').on('click', 'a', function(){})
```

is *not* equivalent to

```
$('a.delete').live('click',function(){})`
```

These do two different things.

Your `.live()` one is actually attaching an event to `document` and then checking to see if the element *actually* clicked was a child `<a class="delete">` tag.

In your `.on()` example, you are trying to bind an event to a `<delete>` element, and check to see if the *actual* element triggered was a child `<a>`.  This is obviously not what you want.

If your elements are being added to the page dynamically, then you can try:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.delete', function(){});
```

This will be the same as your `.live()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you changing the selector?

```
$('a.delete').live('click',function(){})
```

should be changed to:

```
$('a.delete').on('click',function(){})
```

or

```
$('a.delete').click(function(){})
```

Comment: if it's dynamic he'll need to use the delegation method.